# Simplemodal in <td>

Tags: jquery, iframe, html-table, simplemodal

I am trying pass links to simplemodal from :

```
<td><a href="games/BG-1001.php" class ="simple_modal" >EU-ch U12</a></td>
```

and at the bottom of http://chesstao.com/test-1.php I have code for picking up the URL and for loading the iframe (but it is commented out).

```
<script src="js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.1-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/basic-min.js"></script>

<script>
// Display an external page using an iframe
//var src = "http://365.ericmmartin.com/";

$("a").attr("href")
$('.simple_modal').click(function() {
var hrefval= $(this).attr("href");

});


//$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
//closeHTML:"", containerCss:{backgroundColor:"#fff", borderColor:"#fff",
//height:450, padding:0, width:830}, overlayClose:true}); </script>
```

The problem is that I can't use a literal to set src: 
    var src = "http://365.ericmmartin.com/"; //DW

because the URL in the table data changes.

Can somebody please tell me how to blend the commented code with the other code?. Am I correct in my assessment?

Comment: I know. I have been trying every modal and lightbox I could find to produce popups for chess gamescores. Most candidates use rel="" which  won't validate in HTML5. But I will take your comment under advisement.

Comment: I will comply with your suggestion.

Comment: How do I indicate that the solution was acceptable? I don't see how...

Comment: Click the checkmark to the left of the answer you want to mark as accepted

Comment: Thanks, I'll set that accepted toggle every time I can.

Comment: No problem, glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply calling the `modal()` method from inside your click event?

```
$('.simple_modal').click(function(e) {
    // Get the href value of the <a> that was clicked
    var hrefval= $(this).attr("href");

    // Insert the href value into the parameter of the modal() method
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + hrefval + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {closeHTML:"", containerCss:{backgroundColor:"#fff", borderColor:"#fff", height:450, padding:0, width:830}, overlayClose:true});

    // preventDefault() stops the default behavior of the <a> that was clicked
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is a [simplified JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zAxAB/)